box several horizontally connected cells in an array. Is there a command similar to \Aboxed?
I would like to box several horizontally connected cells in an array. \Aboxed from mathtools is only working for two horizontally adjacent cells, and is omitting any extra cells.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\textbackslash Aboxed works for ``boxing'' two horizontally adjacent cells in an array.
\[
    \begin{array}{lclcl}
        \Aboxed{1&+}&1&=&2
    \end{array}
\]
However, when I try to box more horizontally connected cells, it does not work. In fact, every cell except the first two are omitted.
\[
    \begin{array}{lclcl}
        \Aboxed{1&+&1&=&2}
    \end{array}
\]
How can I overcome this?
\end{document}


As the example boxes all the columns, I could have used \hline but I use \cline here to show the form that could just box a range of columns.

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

However, when I try to box more horizontally connected cells, it does not work. In fact, every cell except the first two are omitted.
\[
    \begin{array}{lclcl}
      1&+&1&=&2\\
      \cline{1-5}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l}{1}&+&1&=&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{2}\\
      \cline{1-5}
        1&+&1&=&2\\
    \end{array}
\]
How can I overcome this?
\end{document}


You may exploit the hf-tikz package.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{lclcl}
  1&+&1&=&2 \\
  \tikzmarkin{A}
  1&+&1&=&2
  \tikzmarkend{A} \\
  1&+&1&=&2
\end{array}
\]

\begin{align}
a &= b+c+d \\
\tikzmarkin{B}
f &= g+h \\
u &= v+w
\tikzmarkend{B}
\end{align}

\end{document}

Look at the package manual for how to customize.

